# An assignment operator inside an assignment operator

Tags: javascript, operators

```
'use strict';

let apples = '3';
let bananas = '4';

console.log(+apples + (apples = +bananas + 3));
```

The output is 10, unexpectedly. I thought it would be 14, and the compiler would think something like this

1. console.log(+apples + (apples = +bananas + 3));
2. console.log(+apples + (apples = 4 + 3));
3. console.log(+apples + (apples = 7)); //the variable 'apples' is going to be 7
4. console.log(+apples + 7); //'apples' now equals to 7
5. console.log(7 + 7);
6. console.log(14)
7. 14

But on the step 4, 'apples' apparently equals to 3. Why isn't the output 14?

---

update: Can it be that there are parentheses around each operand, which are automatically added even though not directly written?

1. console.log((+apples) + ((apples = (+bananas) + (3)))); //since parentheses now have equal precedence(order), actions are done from left to right
2. console.log(3 + (apples = 4 + 3));
3. console.log(3 + (apples = 7)); //the variable 'apples' is going to be 7
4. console.log(3 + 7); //'apples' now equals to 7
5. console.log(3 + 7);
6. console.log(10)
7. 10

That would, I think, logically explain why there is 10 instead of 14.

---

Sorry for clumsy code. I was just doing some practice after reading about operators in js.

Comment: @Sanmeet you have to use @ in order to notify a user in the comments

Comment: You can use https://astexplorer.net/ to check the order of expression evaluation. Here's a [gist with your code](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0b6a9470b2ce62d6d42ebbc5ebd0e3f0/5dfc08902318ce2086328d4d91bd317db936022f). Expand the expression tree on the right and it will highlight the code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On step 4, value of `apples` isn't 7 because the expression in your code example is evaluated from left to right.

So the following expression:

```
+apples + (apples = +bananas + 3)
```

is evaluated as:

1. Coerce the value of `apples` to a number

   ```
   3 + (apples = +bananas + 3)
   ```
2. Coerce the value of `bananas` to a number

   ```
   3 + (apples = 4 + 3)
   ```
3. Add 4 + 3 and assign the result of addition to `apples`

   ```
   3 + (apples = 7)
   ```
4. `(apples = 7)` - value of this expression is 7

   ```
   3 + 7
   ```

Final result = 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I still have a question: how can it be that coercion of 'apples' in your first step occured before stuff in parentheses?

Comment: Addition operator evaluates its operands from left to right. [Ecmascript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) mentions the steps taken to evaluate the operands of the addition operator.